# xml schema: restricting occurrences to sibling element sequence cardinality

Tags: xsd

Given:

```
<xs:complexType name="SymbolsList" final="">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="symbol" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ComboList">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="combo" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="symbol" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="comboName" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="symbolsList" type="SymbolsList">
  <xs:unique name="uniqueSymbol">
    <xs:selector xpath="./symbol" />
    <xs:field xpath="@name" />
  </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="combosList" type="ComboList">
  <xs:unique name="uniqueCombo">
    <xs:selector xpath="./combo" />
    <xs:field xpath="@comboName" />
  </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

I believe this defines a list of symbols and a list of combinations of those symbols.
The each entry in the list of symbols must have a unique name, and each entry in the list of combos must have a unique comboName.
What I'd like to know is if there is a way for me to restrict the number of allowed occurrences in the combosList sequence to at least the number of symbols defined in the symbol list.

I guess I'm asking whether or not cardinality restriction can be variable and if so, how to associate it's limitation?

I also want to make it so that the comboList elements (a single combo) can only use names of symbols defined in the symbolList element.

I think I can pull of that last part. I can't find anything anywhere that talks about limiting caridinal sizes of disparate element sequences to greater than or equal to one or the other.

Perhaps it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

XSD requires cardinality to constraints to be specified literally in the declaration; the kind of dynamic calculation you have in mind is not in XSD's design space.

In XSD 1.1 you can add an assertion to some common ancestor of SymbolsList and CombosList that requires

```
count(CombosList/combo) ge count(SymbolsList/symbol)
```

XSD 1.1 is supported by Saxon EE and by Xerces J (in the latter case you have to look for the 1.1 distribution, or did last I looked).  (One caveat:  Note that Xerces J does not support all of XPath 2.0 in assertions, and I haven't actually checked to see whether this assertion is covered by the minimal subset of XPath XSD requires of conforming 1.1 implementations.  Investigate further before sinking a lot of time here.)

Comment: Right now I'm using LiquidXML tools in windows, and compiling the output of those tools in linux. Does liquidXML allow XSD 1.1?